# Method-call compile error

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public class LoginSql {

    Conexion con = new Conexion();
    con.conexionDB(); // error here <           
}
```

package con does not exist
but exist

```
public class Conexion {
    public Connection conexionDB(){

       Connection link = null;
       return link
    }       
}
```

I using package example

```
com.hi.pro
com.hi.pro.class
com.hi.pro.sql
```

I have code in `com.hi.pro.sql` but not work

[image: Netbeans Screenshot]

only work in the com.hi.pro in class app.java
[image: Second Netbeans Screenshot]

Comment: Does your `LoginSql` class contains just those two statement? Nothing else? No methods? If yes, then there's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that this statement:

```
con.conexionDB();
```

... is just a method call statement. That can't sit directly inside a class - it needs to be in a method, constructor, or initializer block. You probably want to put it in a constructor:

```
public class LoginSql {
    private Conexion con = new Conexion();

    public LoginSql() {
        con.conexionDB();
    }
}
```

The *declaration* of `con` is fine, because that's an instance variable declaration, which *is* allowed directly inside a class declaration.

Note that this has *nothing* to do with packages. It's purely a matter of trying to put a statement in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

call that method inside some method or constructor.

like

```
public void createConnection(){
   con.conexionDB();
}
```

OR

```
public LoginSql(){
    con.conexionDB();
}
```

Hope that helps